# How to remove (squash) unnamed git branches

Tags: git

I have a git repo with an absurdly complex tree. I want to simplify that tree so that all the unnamed branches will be a simple commit and just one line remains in the tree.

I have tried to:

1. remove commits by interactive rebase
2. squash all the commits in the unnamed branches

In both cases, I have issues with submodules conflicts. The repo over which I am working is this one: [link](https://framagit.org/sapo/ph.d.-project/-/network/master).

For future reference, I leave here the present status of the git graph log:

```
*   9b0bc07 - (HEAD -> master, origin/master, origin/HEAD) Merge branch 'master' of https://framagit.org/sapo/ph.d.-project (16 hours ago) 
|\  
| * df5584b - Finished methods description and analysis (18 hours ago) 
| * 665d714 - Update comparison/README.md (20 hours ago) 
| * 6e31ac5 - Update comparison/README.md (5 days ago) 
| * b33094e - Update README.md (5 days ago) 
| *   336f5ad - Resolved merge (6 days ago) 
| |\  
| | * 1fba1c9 - Reorganized readme (7 days ago) 
| | * 12a313c - Still debugging, problem with polyphony (9 days ago) 
| | * 744ad4b - Still debugging runPlyAlignment (10 days ago) 
| | * 429fd13 - Added few modules. polyAlignment should work now, to be tested (13 days ago) 
| | *   25a83e6 - Finished broad_alingment, doing precise (13 days ago) 
| | |\  
| | | * 7a26990 - Update README.md (2 weeks ago) 
| | | * ccf7532 - Now tracking edited AMPACT code (3 weeks ago) 
| | | * 67a7d31 - Added configuration file for managing experiments (3 weeks ago) 
| | | * f2dafb9 - Error in Bach10 number of notes and loading sources (3 weeks ago) 
| | | * 16c4fe0 - Update comparison/README.md (4 weeks ago) 
| | | * 2983292 - updated datasets (4 weeks ago) 
| | | * 245f36e - Added symbolic link to utils (5 weeks ago) 
| | | * 202ee49 - Removed double submodule utils (5 weeks ago) 
| | | * 6a7ca53 - Updating  datasets (5 weeks ago) 
| | | * 0b25e03 - Trying to solve submodule issue (5 weeks ago) 
| | | * 96b4d90 - Moved utils to submodule (5 weeks ago) 
| | | * d4e7dc2 - Moved datasets to submodule (5 weeks ago) 
| | | * 667492c - Add LICENSE (5 weeks ago) 
| | | * 3882ad0 - Initial commit (5 weeks ago) 
| | * 253c3ea - Now tracking edited AMPACT code (3 weeks ago) 
| | * 022d483 - Added configuration file for managing experiments (3 weeks ago) 
| | * 557daba - Error in Bach10 number of notes and loading sources (3 weeks ago) 
| | * 434e3ae - Update comparison/README.md (4 weeks ago) 
| | * 66bc782 - updated datasets (4 weeks ago) 
| | * 1099294 - Added symbolic link to utils (5 weeks ago) 
| | * 7b43ae8 - Removed double submodule utils (5 weeks ago) 
| | * ae824ac - Updating  datasets (5 weeks ago) 
| | * 37dceed - Trying to solve submodule issue (5 weeks ago) 
| | * 2d83417 - Moved utils to submodule (5 weeks ago) 
| | * f11aa29 - Moved datasets to submodule (5 weeks ago) 
| | * 24a6b04 - Add LICENSE (5 weeks ago) 
| | * dd1e88d - Initial commit (5 weeks ago) 
| * a342f5e - Start tracking midiVelocity code and added dependencies for toyExampleRunScript (6 days ago) 
| * f2f8c48 - Still debugging, problem with polyphony (9 days ago) 
| * f7ede7a - Still debugging runPlyAlignment (10 days ago) 
| * 8f3b455 - Added few modules. polyAlignment should work now, to be tested (13 days ago) 
| *   415431e - Finished broad_alingment, doing precise (13 days ago) 
| |\  
| | * a6907a7 - Update README.md (2 weeks ago) 
| | * ab075bc - Now tracking edited AMPACT code (3 weeks ago) 
| | * 7f41e99 - Added configuration file for managing experiments (3 weeks ago) 
| | * cf925d6 - Error in Bach10 number of notes and loading sources (3 weeks ago) 
| | * eb2ffa4 - Update comparison/README.md (4 weeks ago) 
| | * a6b3992 - updated datasets (4 weeks ago) 
| | * 3f28358 - Added symbolic link to utils (5 weeks ago) 
| | * fb8c1db - Removed double submodule utils (5 weeks ago) 
| | * 99c6b86 - Updating  datasets (5 weeks ago) 
| | * 63646c3 - Trying to solve submodule issue (5 weeks ago) 
| | * 08cdad7 - Moved utils to submodule (5 weeks ago) 
| | * dc270c3 - Moved datasets to submodule (5 weeks ago) 
| | * 23a7cae - Add LICENSE (5 weeks ago) 
| | * 8aa959d - Initial commit (5 weeks ago) 
| * 95c1561 - Now tracking edited AMPACT code (3 weeks ago) 
| * 755842e - Added configuration file for managing experiments (3 weeks ago) 
| * 87ef237 - Error in Bach10 number of notes and loading sources (3 weeks ago) 
| * ad7de96 - Update comparison/README.md (4 weeks ago) 
| * e8306d8 - updated datasets (4 weeks ago) 
| * 6c56644 - Added symbolic link to utils (5 weeks ago) 
| * 83dc5e5 - Removed double submodule utils (5 weeks ago) 
| * 4d3480a - Updating  datasets (5 weeks ago) 
| * cd17adb - Trying to solve submodule issue (5 weeks ago) 
| * 8cee7fa - Moved utils to submodule (5 weeks ago) 
| * 51eb100 - Moved datasets to submodule (5 weeks ago) 
| * 654ad09 - Add LICENSE (5 weeks ago) 
| * ffe8f95 - Initial commit (5 weeks ago) 
* cde3680 - Added ewert-mueller-synch-method (16 hours ago) 
* 26ed69f - Finished methods description and analysis (18 hours ago) 
* de98e01 - Update comparison/README.md (20 hours ago) 
* 3a2f81c - Update comparison/README.md (5 days ago) 
* 1bbaf02 - Update README.md (5 days ago) 
*   08e1719 - Resolved merge (6 days ago) 
|\  
| * 3442cf3 - Reorganized readme (7 days ago) 
| * c9a382e - Still debugging, problem with polyphony (9 days ago) 
| * 6eeaa55 - Still debugging runPlyAlignment (10 days ago) 
| * 9ee5b09 - Added few modules. polyAlignment should work now, to be tested (13 days ago) 
| *   72cc527 - Finished broad_alingment, doing precise (13 days ago) 
| |\  
| | * 1fa24ce - Update README.md (2 weeks ago) 
| | * 65d8ec3 - Now tracking edited AMPACT code (3 weeks ago) 
| | * 90c2fcd - Added configuration file for managing experiments (3 weeks ago) 
| | * 0dfab99 - Error in Bach10 number of notes and loading sources (3 weeks ago) 
| | * 8adc63b - Update comparison/README.md (4 weeks ago) 
| | * 8f37d17 - updated datasets (4 weeks ago) 
| | * 2731ac6 - Added symbolic link to utils (5 weeks ago) 
| | * 7d3e966 - Removed double submodule utils (5 weeks ago) 
| | * 29486c3 - Updating  datasets (5 weeks ago) 
| | * 4da21a2 - Trying to solve submodule issue (5 weeks ago) 
| | * 113978b - Moved utils to submodule (5 weeks ago) 
| | * 147df61 - Moved datasets to submodule (5 weeks ago) 
| | * 0c49f6f - Add LICENSE (5 weeks ago) 
| | * b5edea7 - Initial commit (5 weeks ago) 
| * 647f169 - Now tracking edited AMPACT code (3 weeks ago) 
| * 06f03b8 - Added configuration file for managing experiments (3 weeks ago) 
| * d3da2bf - Error in Bach10 number of notes and loading sources (3 weeks ago) 
| * f2056cc - Update comparison/README.md (4 weeks ago) 
| * ed2d32b - updated datasets (4 weeks ago) 
| * 5f76af1 - Added symbolic link to utils (5 weeks ago) 
| * a36d228 - Removed double submodule utils (5 weeks ago) 
| * ff56e6c - Updating  datasets (5 weeks ago) 
| * a8113f6 - Trying to solve submodule issue (5 weeks ago) 
| * 439bbe6 - Moved utils to submodule (5 weeks ago) 
| * f1900ac - Moved datasets to submodule (5 weeks ago) 
| * 4b95c5c - Add LICENSE (5 weeks ago) 
| * 4452ced - Initial commit (5 weeks ago) 
* f6cf1b3 - Start tracking midiVelocity code and added dependencies for toyExampleRunScript (6 days ago) 
* bcc62dc - Still debugging, problem with polyphony (9 days ago) 
* 2e35a6e - Still debugging runPlyAlignment (10 days ago) 
* 671a59e - Added few modules. polyAlignment should work now, to be tested (13 days ago) 
*   84228aa - Finished broad_alingment, doing precise (13 days ago) 
|\  
| * 1e96218 - Update README.md (2 weeks ago) 
| * 04a420f - Now tracking edited AMPACT code (3 weeks ago) 
| * 6fbf6cf - Added configuration file for managing experiments (3 weeks ago) 
| * 9ba12b1 - Error in Bach10 number of notes and loading sources (3 weeks ago) 
| * 0652851 - Update comparison/README.md (4 weeks ago) 
| * a5d23af - updated datasets (4 weeks ago) 
| * 750e8bd - Added symbolic link to utils (5 weeks ago) 
| * 48f2509 - Removed double submodule utils (5 weeks ago) 
| * cf92067 - Updating  datasets (5 weeks ago) 
| * 79b804b - Trying to solve submodule issue (5 weeks ago) 
| * df419cb - Moved utils to submodule (5 weeks ago) 
| * 5f616a4 - Moved datasets to submodule (5 weeks ago) 
| * 9e07d9b - Add LICENSE (5 weeks ago) 
| * 04d3e95 - Initial commit (5 weeks ago) 
* 175279a - Now tracking edited AMPACT code (3 weeks ago) 
* 79b209f - Added configuration file for managing experiments (3 weeks ago) 
* 1489f41 - Error in Bach10 number of notes and loading sources (3 weeks ago) 
* 0cfdded - Update comparison/README.md (4 weeks ago) 
* 83c0006 - updated datasets (4 weeks ago) 
* d9ec598 - Added symbolic link to utils (5 weeks ago) 
* 00429a4 - Removed double submodule utils (5 weeks ago) 
* bd2c942 - Updating  datasets (5 weeks ago) 
* 88d7305 - Trying to solve submodule issue (5 weeks ago) 
* d3a0519 - Moved utils to submodule (5 weeks ago) 
* 3dcb36e - Moved datasets to submodule (5 weeks ago) 
* 84462c3 - Add LICENSE (5 weeks ago) 
* 5e49895 - Initial commit (5 weeks ago)
```

Comment: That graph looks fine. What's the problem with it? Showing the history and development of a project is kind of the purpose of git.

Comment: All those unnamed branches were unwanted and created by a bad automated tool I was using. Most of the commits are duplicated and this has no meaning, since they are all made by me.

Comment: I would accept the history for what it is and just stop using the automated tool for here. Out of interest, what tool was it?

Comment: This is an absurdly *simple* tree. Sorry to mention it.

Comment: Well, it's complex if you think that it's made by just one person with just one branch. All those branches are completely unuseful.

Comment: By the way, I don't actually mind what you really think about this tree, for my purposes it's too complex. How can I put it in a single line?

Comment: harmonica141's answer is fine, you would have to look at branching models. (and for the record, I was not "judging" your tree in any way, I was just trying to hint at the big picture : git is often used to handle so complex situations that this one looks quite straightforward)

Comment: Btw I'm happy to help with branching models on a more detailed basis. But this is some methodological way to go first deciding what you need (as I do not know how you will continue in this repo) before implementing something concrete.

Comment: I usually work with one branch and sometimes slightly different branches when I am unsure on how to go on. Basically, I am no a developer and I do not have to follow hard agile strategies and so on, but just to have my work done a tracked down so that I can go back if some implementation was wrong.

Comment: But the submodule conflicts are something you will not easily get rid of. If you were using different versions of some submodules during the course of writing (which seems to be the case) the arising merge conflicts will be hard so solve and impose a great danger of losing work (because you deleted history by then). This is why we all so strongly recommend not to shorten it. You can merge as much as you want, reduce it down to just one branch if you like, but please keep the history. Everything else is not done easily.

Comment: I solved by creating another branch and by hard-resetting to the target commit, then soft resetting to the last commit in the new branch and committing the results.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking at your linked repository I see why the question is arising. A PhD thesis on git is a cool thing to do but something entirely different from the development of a software project. Nonetheless partly the same rules apply. Having a longer history provides you with backups. I strongly recommend not taking those away as you may regret it at some later point in time... (telling from experience...)

Git as a version tracking tool exists for the sole purpose of keeping history. So squashing commits simply to make the tree less complex is the equivalent of burning history books.

To reduce complexity on the repository and restore maintainability you may want to refactor in order to implement a consistent branching scheme. There are several out there for any purpose and complexity of project. Maybe you have a look around in the [git documentation](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Branching-Branching-Workflows) or over at the Bitbucket guys from [Atlassian](https://www.atlassian.com/git/tutorials/comparing-workflows).

A very popular branching model though is [git flow](https://buildmedia.readthedocs.org/media/pdf/git-flow/latest/git-flow.pdf). The basic idea is to have a continuous development branch that you merge new features (each being developed on a separate branch) into and from which releases emerge into a stable branch. Each feature branch is closed after the feature is finished so the number of open branches is naturally limited. Basically in this workflow branches are used to sort code by its stability, starting from separate feature branches that can not even live on their own up to an ever trustworthy stable release branch. Please note that there are helper scripts to do the hard work for you in this workflow. It makes cl work really easy.

It also is important to recognize bad software. If there is a automated tool creating wild unnamed branches without order and permission this is definitely a sign of bad software. Start taking git responsibility yourself and use something you can control. If you do not want to use the command line for some reasons then at least make use of a good gui tool like Gitkraken or Git Tower.

Take some time to find a branching model that suits your needs and then refactor the repository to enforce it. This will help you keep track of the ongoing work.

By the way, what you show in the picture is far from complex. It is just getting lengthy. But as work continues on a project you will accumulate quite a number of commits. This will become more extreme the more developers work on the same repository. There is no need or reason to shorten history, only to enforce law and order to keep it comprehensible.